# Style and position on footer whit 3 colums

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this footer containing 3 columns. The problem is they won't move when i try to style them in css. I have tried the flexbox property but it won't work and i can't think of anything else. In the image down below you can see that the footer is to small and it's not alinged in center.

Html :

> ```
> <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 footer ">
>     <div class="box-1">
>       <h2>CONTACT</h2>
>       <p> <span class="phone">+902385203</span> </p>
>       <p> <span class="phone">+12412412</span>  </p>
>       <p> <span class="phone">124312412</span> </p><br>
>       <p></p>
>       <a class="phone" href="#">Myceliumtour@gmail.com</a>
>       <br>
>       <p></p>
>
>
>       <p> <span class="phone">Balan, 535200</span> </p>
>       <p> <span class="phone">Harghita, Romania</span>  </p><br>
>
>       <div class="links">
>         <i id="fb" class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
>         <i id="yt"class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
>
>       </div>
>
>
>
>     </div>
>     <div class="box-2">
>       <a href="#"> <img src="logo1.png" alt="footerlogo"> </a>
>
>     </div>
>     <br>
>     <div class="box-3">
>         <h2>CONTENTS</h2><br>
>         <p> <span>ABOUT</span> </p>
>         <p> <span>STORIES</span> </p>
>         <p> <span>CONTACT</span> </p><br>
>
>
>
>     </div>
> </div>
> <hr>
> ```

CSS:

> ```
> .footer{
>   display: flex;
>   justify-content: space-between;
>   justify-content: space-around;
>   position: relative;
>   align-content: flex-start;
>   
>   }
> ```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not saying what you're trying to achieve...

Do you want the footer content placed in the middle of the row?

If that's the case, remove the css and just add `class="d-flex justify-content-center"` to your footer div.
That's it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is because of the class that you gave to the footer. Why is it there `col-md-6` and `col-lg-4` ? Try to take that off and see if it works, because by looking at the image it looks like its using 1/3 of the screen, which is expected by using `col-lg-4`.

A hint, give the footer a `background-color` so you can see if it is with 100% of the screen `width`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please check the your class and my class from this image
and also my css for the flex

Answer (score 1):

Use this property in your class inside and your problem will be solve.

-ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
flex: 0 0 100%;
max-width: 100%